# Passing php array result to javascript variable ( For Creating simple Calendar Event)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Currently I'm creating a simple [calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il3eO.png) with javascript and php using mysqli so I'm trying to pass all my records from database to a variable in javascript so that I can use it to display in my calendar to show a date as [event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIGYy.png) when I click the date which is the [25th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkAeh.png) it will display the data.

this is my [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6oqj.png) I want to display

My php code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "calendar";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bootstrap" ;
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$myArray = array();
    
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $myArray[] = $row['title'];                   
    }
} 
else {
    print_r ($myArray); 
}
?>
```

Here is the part of my javascript I want to pass the result from my query

Javascript code

```
  //here I want to pass the array result from my query in php     
  var codropsEvents = {
 '08-25-2021' : '<span>New Year\'s day</span>',
 '11-23-2021' : '<span>Second Event</span>,
 '12-2-2021'  : '<span>Last Event</span>   
  };
```

Comment: I think if you did a little research on AJAX that would suit this situation quite nicely

Comment: Create the PHP array in the format you want (with the date in the correct format as key) and use `json_encode()` to turn it into a JS object. Then you can can do as @RiggsFolly suggested, call your PHP using Ajax from JS to get the result.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok thank you I will try to do what you said Im just a little bit confused on using the json_code() but I will try to look some for some example

Comment: [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is what you need to use to turn the PHP array into a proper JS object.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes I made the result from my query as a json_encode() now my new problem is how will I put it inside my variable as array? like this 
var codropsEvents = {
 '08-25-2021' : '<span>New Year\'s day</span>', 
 '08-26-2021' : '<span>New Event 1</span>',
 '08-27-2021' : '<span>New Event 2</span>'};

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ive been trying this  var text = '<?php echo json_encode($myArray) ?> ';
    var myArr = JSON.parse(text);
    for(var i = 0; i < myArr .length; i++) {
    var obj = myArr[i];
    console.log(obj);
    var codropsEvents = new Object();
    codropsEvents.obj  = '<span>'+ obj  +'</span>'; 
} but it doesnt work